# Cactus id: Echinopsis aurea?

Tags: identification, succulents, cactus

I have two specimens and I am trying to positively identify them. So far, I am thinking both are varieties of Echinopsis(Lobivia) aurea. I am far from sure though. So, am I any close with my guess?

## Specimen 1:

#### Spines & early buds:

[image]

#### Mature buds:

[image]

#### Flowers:

[image]
[image]

## Specimen 2:

#### Spines & early buds:

[image]
[image]

#### Mature buds:

[image]

#### Flowers:

[image]
[image]

Comment: These are wonderful pictures.  Hey, I was born in AZ.  Didn't learn much except to NOT go running around at night.  Definitely Barrel Cactus but trying to decipher the species and variety will take someone that knows these cactus by sight.  The pictures on this internet never say ANYTHING about what one is looking at...shoot.  Beautiful wonderful amazing plants these cactus.  Someone else will  be able to narrow this down...sorry.